# Loading closed app from pendingintent using a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am creating a chat app using GCM.

The app starts at MainActivity, user enters there username and I register the user, save gcm info(name & device id) on web server and in SharedPreferences and then I load the list of users in MainActivity. I click a user in list, open ChatActivity with extras(myname, his name, his device id). I get a msg from him, I receive a notification with pending intent and the broadcast receiver updates chat timeline, if i click notification it opens ChatActivity with the updated chat timeline,  everything is working well.

The problem occurs when the app is closed and I receive a notification. When I click the notification my app is suppose to open ChatActivity for that particular user and populate chat timeline with the new message.

What is happening is that the ChatActivity loads but since it was closed it did not go through the registration, so it doesn't know who the active user is and doesn't load the new message.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Intent for the Notification (the one wrapped in the PendingIntent), put the same Extras that you put in the Intent when clicking on a user in the list from MainActivity. Given that you have this information available when you create the Notification

Comment: What you said worked but when I click the notification and the window timeline is already open it stacks on top, how to fix? And if I get information sent and the new window is open the extras disappear from subsequent msgs.

Comment: To reopen the same activity window set in the manifest.xml for the ChatActivity: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. This way any existing instances of the Activity will be reused, and put on top. Hopefully this will also solve the problem of the extras disappearing.

Comment: You cannot use `singleTask` launch mode here, as `ChatActivity` is not the root Activity. In general you don't want to use that launch mode anyway, it is for very special cases. Launch mode "singleTop" should do the trick. You may need to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` in order to get the behaviour you need (depending on whether `ChatActivity` can launch other activities on top of itself)

Comment: That partially fixed the extras and the overlapping window. I adding a id to notifications, so each one will be distinct.